# php upload failed - syntax error, unexpected end of file on the line

Tags: php, file-upload

Hi I am trying to upload a file by using php and this is my code. My error is syntax error, unexpected end of file on line 56 which is the end of my code. Anyone can do me a favor? And also where should I create my '/uploads/' filder. I am using XAMMP.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        Upload  
    </title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Uploading files</h1>
<?php 
    if($_FILES['userfile']['error'])
    {
        echo 'Problem: ';
    }

    if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'])) {
        if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'],$upfile)) {
            echo 'Problem: Could not move file to destination directory';
            exit;       
    } else {
        echo 'Problem : Possible file upload attack. Filename:';
        echo $_FILES['username']['name'];
        exit;
    }


    if($_FILES['userfile']['type']!='text/plain'){
        echo 'Problem: File is not plain text.';
        exit;
    }

    $upfile = 'htdocs/snaptrip/uploads/'.$_FILES['userfile']['name'];
    echo 'File uploaded successful<br><br>';

    $contents = file_get_contents($upfile);
    $contents = strip_tags($contents);
    file_put_contents($_FILES['userfile']['name'], $contents);

    echo  n12br($contents);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This block does not have a `}`: `if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'],$upfile)) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your braces don't match. It should be:

```
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'])) {
    if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'],$upfile)) {
        echo 'Problem: Could not move file to destination directory';
        exit;    
    } // This brace was missing   
} else {
```

I suggest you use an IDE that warns about mismatched brackets.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to close `if statement`

```
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'])) {

    // your code

}
^^^ (missing)
```

Comment: Based on the indentation and messages he echoes, I think it's the inner `if` that was unclosed.

Comment: @Barmar i think he forgot to close main `if`.. but as per your suggestion OP needs better IDE for this type of syntax mistake